# How to add range to combo box from webclient C#?

Tags: c#

I want something like this :
`comboBox1.Items.AddRange(webClient.DownloadString("https://pastebin.link"));`
Can someone help me with that or get a list of several lines to combo box.

Comment: What is the content of `webClient.DownloadString("https://pastebin.link")`?

Comment: Downloads string from specified websites.

Comment: The parameter in `AddRange` should be an array. So is there a fixed format for the content in the string? For example, use comma as the delimiter?

Comment: I want to get list in pastebin. But i want it ranged in Combo Box, So i can change the pastebin when i want.

Comment: You should first explain what the string is. Then we can discuss how to convert it to a list

Comment: Basically you can give an example.